# What is the dask version supported for Python 3.5?

Tags: python, python-3.5, dask

Getting python package conflicts when trying to upgrade dask in Conda Python 3.5 environment. The default in a virtual environment created for Python 3.5 is 0.19.

This [thread](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/5447) seemed to indicate 3.6 is supported. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The last version to support Python 3.5 is Dask version 2.6

Comment: Ok. Unable to get dask to upgrade to this version in the virtual environment created for Python 3.5.